# Conditions of train ticket between Vienna and Bratislava

Tags: trains, austria, vienna, slovakia, bratislava

I'm planning a trip to Vienna, and I'd like to visit also Bratislava. I've found a page with prices of train tickets: http://bratislava-slovakia.eu/travel/vienna-bratislava/vienna-train, however, the information presented there is not very clear to me:

1. What is 'Return ticket "Wien Ticket"'? Is it a ticket in one direction only, or back-and-forth ticket?
2. What is 'Ticket valid 1 week'? If I buy such ticket, it mean I can travel back and forth the whole week as often as I want? It could be an option to find accommodation in Vienna or Bratislava and simply travel to the other city each day, instead of moving from one hostel to another.
3. Is this a single person ticket, or it enables to take some 'belonging' such as other person, children, bicycle?

Comment: Below the table it reads: 'Tickets valid one week or one month give you the opportunity to travel there and back multiple times within this time period'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the website of the [Austrian Federal Railways (ÖBB)](http://www.oebb.at) you will find information on what they call [EURegio Slovakia (Bratislava ticket)](http://www.oebb.at/en/Travelling_abroad/EURegio/EURegio_Slovakia/index.jsp). You have several options. For 15 EUR you can buy a return ticket. This ticket has a validity of 4 days, i.e. the return trip has to be done within 4 days. For 34 EUR you can buy a ticket for a week and for 103 EUR a monthly ticket. The last two tickets allow you to commute between Vienna and Bratislava during a calendar week, respectively during a calendar month.

The EURegio ticket can also be used for public transport in Bratislava, during the first day of its validity.

Bikes are transported for free, and children pay half the price. The [detailed regulations](http://www.oebb.at/en/Travelling_abroad/EURegio/EURegio_tariff_regulations/index.jsp) are available on the ÖBB website.